# how to filter Stack Exchange questions with sx.el?

Tags: sx.el

I'm looking for a command like `sx-tab-all-questions`. But instead of 
displaying a list with all communities, I want it to display my list of filters. How can I create a filter, include tags of different communities and highlight new questions ?